# matplotlibのboxplotにおける色などの細かい調整

Tags: python, python3, pandas, matplotlib

pandasでエクセルのデータを読み込み、matplotlib のboxplotで番号ごとにグループ化した箱ひげ図を作成しています。boxplotの箱枠とmedian lineの色を黒で統一したいのですが、色を設定することができません。

boxpropsやmedianpropsを使用すると、線の太さは変えられるのですが、色は変わりませんでした。
コードは以下の通りです。

どのようにすれば、色を変えることができるのでしょうか？
できれば、タイトル（MEAN）の上の Boxplot grouped by SrcID_Featも消したいです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

version: python 3.6.5

```
import os
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame, Series
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_excel("training.xls")

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

boxprops = dict(color="black", linewidth=1.5)
medianprops = dict(color="black",linewidth=1.5)

df.boxplot(column=["MEAN"],by="SrcID_Feat",ax=ax,
      boxprops=boxprops,medianprops=medianprops)

plt.grid(False)
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 全部ではないですが、この辺が参考になるのでは？ [matplotlibのボックスプロットの細かい調整をする(ボックスの枠線、髭、外れ値を調整する)](http://nishimoto-blog.hatenablog.com/entry/2017/09/10/191457), [matplotlibのboxplotの色を変える](https://qiita.com/ShoheiKojima/items/e11240de50ddfadecba7), [matplotlib – seaborn.boxplotの特定のボックスに色を割り当てる](https://codeday.me/jp/qa/20190304/358320.html), [ボックスプロット](https://stats.biopapyrus.jp/python/boxplot.html)

Comment: @kunif さん、ありがとうございます。参照してくださったサイトはすべて確認したのですが、解決できませんでした。
おそらくデータをグループに集約してプロットしていること、あるいはaxes構文が邪魔をしている印象です。

データ数が膨大なため、元データを直すのも億劫でして…。

Comment: pandasのDataFrame経由でboxplotを呼んでいるから自由度が下がっているのでは？ matplotlibの方で呼び出せば出来るのではないですか？

Comment: @kunif さん、ありがとうございます。解決いたしました。お手数お掛けいたしました。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

こんな感じでどうでしょうか

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# データはダミー
N = 10000
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'MEAN':np.random.normal(0.5, 0.1, N),
    'SrcID_Feat':np.random.choice(range(0,10), N)
})

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

bp = df.boxplot(column=["MEAN"],by="SrcID_Feat",ax=ax,return_type='dict')

for box in bp['MEAN']['boxes']:
    box.set_color('black')
    box.set_linewidth(2.0)

for median in bp['MEAN']['medians']:
    median.set_color('black')
    median.set_linewidth(2.0)

plt.grid(False)
plt.show()
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: ありがとうございます！解決いたしました。